# Nodemailer. createTestAccount and cypress: generate same email address

Tags: email, caching, cypress, nodemailer

I created an E2E to test for signups, using Nodemailer with Ethereal.

When the test runs the first time everything ends smoothly, but when I executed it a second time the test, for some reason, breaks.

While investigating the above issue, I noticed that the `createTestAccount` returns the same email address (unless cypress is restarted).

Here's the function code for `createTestAccount`: https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/lib/nodemailer.js#L58.

- Is `createTestAccount` using an internal cache?
- If yes, is there a way to disable it (besides setting and `process.env.ETHEREAL_CACHE` to false)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the current version (6.7.4) of code, it's not possible to disable the cache any other way than setting the env variable `ETHEREAL_CACHE` to something different than  `['true', 'yes', 'y', '1']`.

Aka `process.env.ETHEREAL_CACHE` needs to be `false`

Keep in mind that this is OS level env variable. Not the ones [setup in Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables).
*And the best thing is the great documentation which mentions ETHEREAL_CACHE variable ...*

Answer (score 0):

```
const request = require("request");

async function createEmail (callback) {

    request.post({
        headers: { "content-type" : "application/json" },
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://api.nodemailer.com/user",
        body: Buffer.from(
            JSON.stringify({
                requestor: "nodemailer",
                version: "6.7.8"
            })
        )
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        
        if(err)
            return callback("Failed to handle request!");
        
        const data = JSON.parse(body) || null;
        
        if(typeof(data) !== "object" || typeof(data.status) !== "string")
            return callback("Failed to resolve data");
        
        delete data.status;
        return callback(false, data);

    });

};

createEmail((err, account) => {

    if(err)
        return console.log(err);
    
    console.log(account);

});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).